# Send mail with attachment from cli mac

Tags: macos, outlook, command-line-interface

How can one send a mail with an attachment through outlook on mac using CLI/terminal?
In addition, I would like to send it to multiple people.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will add my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with osascript.

```
osascript /path/to/script/script.scpt "/path/to/attache.file" "subject" "body"
```

The script content

```
on run argv
    set theAttachment to item 1 of argv
    set theAttachment to theAttachment as POSIX file--convert to posix file
    set theSubject to item 2 of argv
    set theContent to item 3 of argv
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        activate
        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent}
        tell theMessage--tell theMessage (not theContent) to add the attachment
            make new attachment with properties {file:theAttachment}
        end tell
    make new recipient at theMessage with properties {email address:{name:"John, Doe", address:"John.Doe@mymail.com"}}
    make new recipient at theMessage with properties {email address:{name:"John, Doe2", address:"John.Doe2@mymail.com"}}
    open theMessage
    end tell
end run
```

That will open a mail, will add the attachment in addition to the DL, subject & body.

Hope it helps.